# Line element not appearing on 2nd and subsequent page of print

Tags: c#, silverlight, printing

I'm printing a set of labels from our Silverlight application. The data to make up the data is read from the database and the UI elements are created on the fly and added to a `Canvas` for layout. The labels are laid out on the page in a grid the number of rows and columns is determined by the paper stock being used.

Everything is working fine apart from the adding of a line to "strike out" an element (for example the original price when an item is on sale):

[image: Label on page one of print]

[image: Label on page two of print]

This is the code that generates the line:

```
var line = new Line { StrokeThickness = 2, Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black) };
line.X1 = 0;
line.SetBinding(Line.Y1Property, new Binding { ElementName = element.Name, Path = new PropertyPath("ActualHeight") });
line.Y2 = 0;
line.SetBinding(Line.X2Property, new Binding { ElementName = element.Name, Path = new PropertyPath("ActualWidth") });
// Insert the element straight after the element it's bound to
canvas.Children.Insert(canvas.Children.IndexOf(element) + 1, line);
line.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, element.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty));
line.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, element.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty));
// and make sure it's Z index is always higher
line.SetValue(Canvas.ZIndexProperty, (int)element.GetValue(Canvas.ZIndexProperty) + 1);
```

- `canvas` is the Canvas being used to display the label
- `element` is the element to be stuck out (in this case the original price).

---

1. The code is getting called for all labels being printed.
2. The bindings are consistent.
3. If I replace the bindings with hard coded values the line gets drawn so it appears to be caused by something in the bindings. However:
4. The `ActualHeight` and `ActualWidth` of the "parent" element are the same for each label.
5. The line isn't being drawn elsewhere on the print out (that I can see). If I stop the output on page one then no lines appear.
6. Everything else is appearing and appearing in the correct place.

What have I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears it was the bindings that were at fault. No matter what I did as soon as I added the bindings back in the lines disappeared - in some cases even from the first page.

In the end the only thing that worked was to change the code to this:

```
element.Measure(new Size(canvas.Width, canvas.Height));
var line = new Line { StrokeThickness = 2, Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black) };
line.X1 = 0.0;
line.Y1 = element.ActualHeight;
line.Y2 = 0.0;
line.X2 = element.ActualWidth;
// Insert the element straight after the element it's bound to
canvas.Children.Insert(canvas.Children.IndexOf(element) + 1, line);
line.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, element.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty));
line.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, element.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty));
// and make sure it's Z index is always higher
line.SetValue(Canvas.ZIndexProperty, (int)element.GetValue(Canvas.ZIndexProperty) + 1);
line.Height = element.ActualHeight;
line.Width = element.ActualWidth;
```

So I "measure" the text element to make sure it's height and width are updated and then set the `Y1`, `X2`, `Height` and `Width` properties directly from the `ActualHeight` and `ActualWidth` of the text element. This draws the line in the correct location and the correct size.